# Create a toggle button with laravelcollective/html

Tags: laravel-5, laravelcollective

I would like to make a checkbox input using toggle button.

The toggle has On/Off options. I would like to use laravelcollective to create this input, but I didnt find any reference regarding this.

My target output should looks like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
  </label>
</div>
```

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
```

My current form:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('is_holiday', 'Holiday Mode:') !!}
        {!! Form::checkbox('is_holiday', array(1 => 'On', 0 => 'Off'),null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
```

Comment: Where do you set `data-toggle` in your code? Have you tried adding it to the array alongside `'class'=>'form-control'`?

Comment: how do i add alongside the array containing the class? should I add 'data-toggle' => 'toggle'?

Comment: Not an expert on the topic, but yes, that array looks like it adds attributes, change `['class'=>'form-control']` to `['class'=>'form-control', 'data-toggle' => 'toggle']`. (Might not work though)